# Archive ad-hoc failing on M1 pro (The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.)

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-m1, fastlane, adhoc

I am using M1 pro macbook and ad-hoc distribution fails.
The wired thing is that distribute to appstore succeed.
i am using fastlane for CLI and pods for frameworks

Xcode : 13.2.1 (13C100)

Ruby : ruby 2.6.8p205

Note:

- i have tried using Rosseta
- i have tried upgrade min version to iOS 13 (my current is 11)

  [this is that happend after ad-hoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBrLD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably i have changed The xcode ruby, and formatting the computer solve my issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).